# c# how to apply WindowState, FormBorderStyle and Bounds changes to multiple forms at once?

Tags: c#, this, bounds, windowstate, formborderstyle

I have buttons in an options menu that i want to be able to change the style of every form at once. At the moment it only applies to the options menu itself because I've used "this."

```
   private void Fullscreen_toggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }

    private void Windowed_toggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    }
```

Is there some way to make this apply globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the [Application.OpenForms()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) collection like this:

```
    private void Fullscreen_toggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            frm.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        }     
    }
```

Comment: that didn't do anything different for me ?

Comment: Works fine for me...but this will only affect forms that are **currently open and displayed** in your app.  It doesn't change the "stored state" of the forms.   If you open another form you'll have to apply the settings to your new instance(s).